# Determine the array index

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a little problem. I have an array with some operations as in the image below
[Image Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAMvG.png)

From the image we see that the other 3 operations are inactive. When I place the correct result on the first operation, operation 2 is activated and so on
. The problem is that the sum is equal to the sum of the last operation

```
sum = RightNumber / LeftNumber;
 Debug.Log(RightNumber + ":" + LeftNumber + "=" + sum);
```

The idea is that I have to calculate my sum of the active operation. How do I take the sum of the first operation, then the second, and so on?

Comment: Show us more of your code. Do you iterate through the array?

Comment: Yes, I initially have an array of 3 inactive operations that I disable in Start ()

Comment: I think I'll find the problem myself because I do not know how to explain it to you to understand